# Simple Cashier Program

Tags: math, currency

private void XButtonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This will close the program
            Close();
        }

```
    private void xButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This will clear all the Text Boxes
        xTextBoxQuantity.Clear();
        xTextBoxPrice.Clear();
        xTextBoxRecieved.Clear();
        xTextBoxSubtotal.Clear();
        xTextBoxTotal.Clear();
        xTextBoxReturn.Clear();

        //This will turn the Return box and Lable back to hidden
        xTextBoxReturn.Visible = false;
        xLableReturn.Visible = false;

    }

    private void XButtonBalance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This will make the Return box and Lable visable
        xLableReturn.Visible = true;
        xTextBoxReturn.Visible = true;

        //Take value from xTextBoxTotal and store it
        Double Total = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxTotal.Text);

       //Take value from xTextBoxRecieved and store it
        double Recieved = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxRecieved.Text);

       //Take value from xTextBoxTotal and subtract from amout recieved
        double Amount = Total - Recieved;

        //Take the Amount and store it in xTextBoxReturn
        xTextBoxReturn.Text = Convert.ToString(Amount);

        //Change color, Red for amount owed and green for amout to give back
        if (Amount < .01) xTextBoxReturn.BackColor = Color.Green;
        else xTextBoxReturn.BackColor = Color.Red;


    }

    private void XButtonTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Take value from xTextBoxQuantity and store it
        Double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxQuantity.Text);

        //Take value from xTextBoxPrice and store it
        Double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxPrice.Text);

        //Peform Muptlication and store it in xTextBoxSubtotal

        Double Subtotal = num1 * num2;
        xTextBoxSubtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(Subtotal);

        //Take the Subtotal and add a 6% sales tax and store it in xTextBoxTotal
        Double SalesTax = Subtotal * 1.06;
        xTextBoxTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(SalesTax);
```

This is my current code and it does work great.  The issue is, I need to make all of the TextBoxes into a currency format.  When I try the math no longer works.  Any ideas will help.  The biggest problem Im' having is with the sales tax when converting it to currency.  I am unable to make the math work if subtotal is in the currency format.  I tried to convert it back to decimal, but when I do I can't run the command Subtotal * 1.0

This is what I changed:

//Take value from xTextBoxTotal and store it

```
        Convert.ToInt16(xTextBoxTotal.Text);
        Double Total = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxTotal.Text); 

       //Take value from xTextBoxRecieved and store it
        double Recieved = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxRecieved.Text);

       //Take value from xTextBoxTotal and subtract from amout recieved
        double Amount = Total - Recieved;

        //Take the Amount and store it in xTextBoxReturn
        xTextBoxReturn.Text = Amount.ToString("C");

        //Change color, Red for amount owed and green for amout to give back
        if (Amount < .01) xTextBoxReturn.BackColor = Color.Green;
        else xTextBoxReturn.BackColor = Color.Red;


    }

    private void XButtonTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Take value from xTextBoxQuantity and store it
        Double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxQuantity.Text);

        //Take value from xTextBoxPrice and store it
        Double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxPrice.Text);

        //Peform Muptlication and store it in xTextBoxSubtotal

        Double Subtotal = num1 * num2;
        xTextBoxSubtotal.Text = Subtotal.ToString("C");

        //Take the Subtotal and add a 6% sales tax and store it in xTextBoxTotal
        Double SalesTax = Subtotal * 1.06;
        xTextBoxTotal.Text = SalesTax.ToString("C");
```

My error is FormatException was unhandled on the Convert.toInt16(xtextboxTotal.text)

Comment: If I change xTextBoxSubtotal.Text = subtotal.toString("C") I am unable to get the sales tax part to work

Comment: Can you clarify 'make the math work'? And how are you making the currency format in the text-boxes, are you using the ToString("") method? Please edit the question to show the source code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When formating a numeric string as currency, you have to parse it back before you can re-convert it back to a numeric form, this depends on the curency formatting rules you used to create the number in the first place.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx

```
string value;
NumberStyles style;
CultureInfo culture;
double number;

// Parse currency value using en-GB culture.
value = "£1,097.63";
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
if (Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
// Displays: 
//       Converted '£1,097.63' to 1097.63.
```